# Is jQl inconsistent or am I using it wrong?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, jquery-plugins

Im using jQl to asynchronously load my jQuery libraries and dependencies, but it appears to only work on every other page load (Im using Ctrl+F5 to ensure the scripts are loaded fresh each time)

I am using like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQl.loadjQ("/Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js");
    jQl.loadjQdep("/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js");
    jQl.loadjQdep("/Scripts/multiselect/jquery.multiselect.min.js");
    jQl.loadjQdep("/Scripts/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.min.js");
</script>
```

Is this not correct? Has anyone else had the same problems?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQl.loadjQ("http://www.webiste.com/Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js");
    jQl.loadjQdep("http://www.webiste.com/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js");
    jQl.loadjQdep("http://www.webiste.com/Scripts/multiselect/jquery.multiselect.min.js");
    jQl.loadjQdep("http://www.webiste.com/Scripts/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.min.js");
</script>
```